# Is there a way to reverse the suspension of form-submission or will it be better not to have it done in the first place?

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I am trying to make a simple web application. In my login page I have a form with a text field, a password and a submit button. Form submission is prevented if either fields are empty. This is the script I use:

```
 function checkLoginCredentials() {
    var usernameFormValue = $("#usernameForm").val().trim();
    var passwordFormValue = $("#passwordForm").val().trim();
    var validated;


    $("#loginForm").submit(function(event){
        if (usernameFormValue === "" || passwordFormValue === "") {
            $("span").html("Enter a username or password");
            validated = false
        } else {
            validated = true;
        }
        return validated;
    });
}
```

However, I noticed that once the script runs and form submission is prevented, the user can no longer make an attempt to log in again. The only alternative I can think of is to have ALL validations done by my login servlet and utility classes. Is there a way around this or must validations of invalid entries like empty strings be done by my Java Classes?

Comment: can't you just add `required` attributes to the <input>s and call it a day? JS only makes this complicated...

Comment: Modern browser support HTML5 validation so no JavaScript is actually needed and you should also be doing all the validation on the server also.

Comment: How is `checkLoginCredentials` called? However you are doing it is what the issue is.

Answer (score 4):

The issue here is how you are assigning the validation code. You have a `checkLoginCredentials` and when you call it you read the form values. And than you add a form submission. You should add the reading of the textbox values inside of the submit method, not outside.

```
$("#loginForm").submit(function(event){

    var usernameFormValue = $("#usernameForm").val().trim(),
        passwordFormValue = $("#passwordForm").val().trim(),
        validated;

    if (usernameFormValue === "" || passwordFormValue === "") {
        $("span").html("Enter a username or password");
        validated = false
    } else {
        validated = true;
    }
    return validated;
});
```

Comment: Tried what you suggested and it worked. Thanks! If it's alright can you explain why I had the form resubmission problem?

Comment: When you call checkLoginCredentials you bind an event handler to the element and you store the value at that moment. The variables do not always have the latest value therefore the event handler you attach always has the original value and will not update. If you were to call checkLoginCredentials, you would bind submit again, it does not override the last one, it appends it to the stack so the call still fails and cancels.